# (MS Dynamics test automation) Can not switch to iframe, frames changing automatically

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, automated-tests, dynamics-365

I am trying to switch frames in MS Dynamics 365 system using Selenium WebDriver. I will explain one of the issues below. Here is the html element code: 
[element code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpBsb.png)

Usually, i used to use id=contentIFrame0 or 1, and the frames were switching fine. The problem is, that MS Dynamics generates those iframes dynamicly, usually contains max 3 iframes(contentIFrame0, contentIFrame1, contentIFrame2), but the fact is that you never know they will be 2 or 1 on the page and why, so if you use today one of them directly - tommorow your tests will fail because of the changes. 
It seems like I have to switch all the time to the last frame, but it works randomly, because sometimes there is the first one contains element and another one scripts. Other thing i tried to do, is to switch to one iframe which has attributes: style =  visibility: visible(before that, i tried to print in console how many visible frames driver sees - but written all the time 0). Also, if i try to print in the console how many iframes there are on the page - the counter is 2, but I can see 3.

If there is anyone who tried to automate MS Dynamics 365 and had the same problem? 
I have discribed probably all cases, maybe you will notice the logics and difference.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works in your case but please give it a try.

If you know one of the elements in the frame which you are trying to switch then use the css selector or xpath

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[title='test']")));
```

Answer (score 0):

It very hard to test in this fashion as Microsoft doesn't guarantee that the objects being rendered will stay the same.  It may be 3 frames today, but in the next version the dev team may introduce more or less, working with the DOM directly is no longer supported.

I would highly recommend the following framework for testing Dynamics: https://github.com/Microsoft/EasyRepro

It will help elevate your testing up one level, it’s introducing a level of abstraction so as to minimize the need to work with HTML directly by isolating all that low-level work in the framework code.

Here is a great post about EasyRepro: http://www.itaintboring.com/dynamics-crm/easy-repro-what-is-it/

Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

This xpath finds the main pane reliably

```
//iframe[contains(contains(@id,'contentIFrame') and contains(@style,'visible')]
```

Note: not applicable to Dynamics 365 Unified Interface, it has completely different DOM.